# CrossListQueryInfo in subsite

Tags: sharepoint, caching, sharepoint-2010

The situation is:
I've got subsite(SPWeb) htp://servername/subsitename/
and i need to use CrossListQueryInfo to find item in all lists but just in this subsite(SPWeb)
i do:

```
 var query = new CrossListQueryInfo
                            {
                                Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"100\" />",
                                ViewFields =  "...",
                                Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />",
                                WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                UseCache = true,
                                Query =  "..."
                            };
var cache = new CrossListQueryCache(query);
var dataTable = cache.GetSiteData(web.Site, CrossListQueryCache.ContextUrl()))
```

but this search in whole sitecollection, what is rigth way to use it? what do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve items only for specific site, specify for [Webs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistqueryinfo.webs.aspx) property empty value.

According to MSDN:

> The **Webs** property specifies which Web sites to include in the query.
>   By default, the query considers only the Web site from which the
>   GetSiteData method was invoked.
>
> You can broaden the scope of the query
>   by setting the Webs property to a string containing a **Webs** tag and a
>   **Scope** attribute. Possible values of the Scope attribute include
>   Recursive and SiteCollection.
>
> ```
> <Webs Scope="Recursive" />
>
> <Webs Scope="SiteCollection" />
> ```
>
> When the Scope attribute is set to Recursive, the query considers the
>   current Web site and all subsites of the current Web site.
>
> When the
>   Scope attribute is set to SiteCollection, the query considers all Web
>   sites that are in the same site collection as the current Web site. Of
>   the two attribute values, this is the more inclusive

---

So, the updated code:

```
var query = new CrossListQueryInfo
                            {
                                Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"100\" />",
                                ViewFields =  "...",
                                Webs = string.Empty,  // considers only the Web site from which the GetSiteData method was invoked
                                WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                UseCache = true,
                                Query =  "..."
                            };
var cache = new CrossListQueryCache(query);
var dataTable = cache.GetSiteData(web.Site, CrossListQueryCache.ContextUrl()))
```